# Error while updating Confluence page using Python

Tags: python, confluence, confluence-rest-api

```
status = confluence.update_page(
parent_id=None,  
page_id={con_pageid},
title={con_title},
body='Updated Page. You can use <strong>HTML tags</strong>!')
```

Using this code gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "update2.py", line 24, in 
> status = confluence.update_page(
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/confluence.py", line 1513, in update_page
> if not always_update and body is not None and self.is_page_content_is_already_updated(page_id, body, title):
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/confluence.py", line 1433, in is_page_content_is_already_updated
> current_title = confluence_content.get("title", None)
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Does anyone have an idea on how to update a confluence page using python? I've tried various solutions provided even here, but none of them is working for me.

Comment: I have tried leaving title blank and a string value but still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tweaked a code that works. Providing whole code in case anyone would need it later.

```
import requests
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://confluence.<your domain>.com',
    token='CyberPunk EdgeRunners')

status = confluence.get_page_by_title(space='ABC', title='testPage')
print(status)

status = confluence.update_page(
    parent_id=<a number sequence>,
    page_id=<a number sequence>,
    title='testpage',
    body='<h1 id="WindowsSignatureSet2.4.131.3-2-HandoffinstructionstoOperations">A</h1>'
) 
print(status)
```

Comment: To check for page id and parent id, on confluence go to the page that you want to update and its parent page respectively. On top right corner, you'd see the ... button. Click on that and click page information from dropdown. The page you'd be directed to contains the required id in it's url.